# Simple question about RC Circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

So I know that a RC Circuit takes time for the capacitor to charge. However, if I remove the resistor would the time for the capacitor take no time to charge? Or does this only happen in ideal states where the resistance throughout the circuit is 0?

Answer (score 1):

If you reduce the resistor value towards 0, the time to charge the capacitor trends toward 0.

In the real world, the minimum resistance is limited by the internal resistance of the voltage source, the internal resistance of the capacitor, and the resistance of the wires connecting them.

Comment: it is useful to note that as the resistor value trends to zero, the instantaneous value of the current trends to infinity: that is, to instantaneously change the value of the voltage across a capacitor requires infinite current. Since there are no infinite current sources in the real world nor ideal resistanceless wires, a very large current source will "find" some other value of resistance in the circuit (as pointed out by @the photon) and  use it to (in mechanical engineering jargon) maintain causality.

Answer (score 0):

The time to charge a capacitor depends not only on the capacitance and resistance, but also on the inductance of the wires and other conductors. Normally the battery has some internal resistance. However, if we use a charged superconductive capacitor as a battery to charge another superconductive capacitor and all wires are also superconductive (a zero resistance), then the time to charge the capacitor would be defined by the capacitance of the capacitors and the inductance of the connecting wires and other conductors. Such a circuit would essentially be an LC resonating circuit gradually losing energy by emitting radio waves.

Comment: So the impedance of the circuit is like adding a inductor to the circuit.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.